# Простое или сложное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

> Иду и пою. Шли и болтали. На улице светло и солнечно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все предложения сложносочинённые:

Иду и пою. -два односоставных опред.-личных

Шли и болтали. - два односоставных неопределённо-личных с одним производителем действия. Однако эта конструкция может быть разобрана и как неполное простое предложение с пропуском подлежащего и однородными сказуемыми в таком контексте: Валя и Костик шли по проспекту. Шли и болтали.

На улице светло и солнечно. - два безличных

Answer (score 2):

Первые два предложения простые с однородными сказуемыми. Последнее - сложное, сложносочинённое, с общим второстепенным членом.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, коллеги,совсем запутали!Самой бы разобраться, а как ребенку объяснить?

Answer (score 1):

Никак не могу понять, почему все эти предложения нельзя считать простыми с однородными сказуемыми.Именно таков мой ответ

Comment: Когда-то было можно, но появились разночтения, и теперь общее мнение учёных: если возможно их считать односоставными, то это односоставное. Вот примеры из Ожегова об отсутствии запятой в ССП:http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm
в)выражены назывными  предложениями: Хриплый стон и скрежет ярый!
г)выражены двумя вопросительными, восклицательными, или побудительными предложениями: Ты понял меня или ударить тебя? 
д)выражены двумя неопределенно-личными предложениями, если имеется в виду один и тот же производитель действия, например:Постояли, потолковали и пошли назад? (Лермонтов);

Comment: http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200304703
Важно осознать отличие односоставных предложений от неполных, в которых тоже может оказаться только один главный член.  1) – Во дворах жгут сухие листья. 2) – Что делают дворники осенью? – Во дворах жгут сухие листья. В первом случае кто  производит действие – не важно. Это – односоставное предложение. Во втором случае сообщается о действии, которое производит определенный субъект – дворники. Подлежащее дворники пропущено, но легко восстанавливается из предшествующего предложения. Значит, второе предложение – двусоставное неполное.

Comment: Иду и пою - подлежащее содержится в значении глагола-я иду и я пою. Лицо определено составом сказуемого, подлежащее не нужно - явно односоставные. На улице светло и солнечно - нет подлежащего и быть не может, это состояние природы - явно безличные. А вот "Шли и болтали" - если даётся без контекста - односоставное, с контекстом и указанием на определённых деятелей - двусоставное неполное.

Comment: >Важно осознать отличие односоставных предложений от неполных, в которых тоже может оказаться только один главный член  
  
Кому важно и для чего? Для обучения, понимания, облегчения восприятия - возможно. С точки зрения грамматики привлечение субъективных критериев типа "легко восстановить из контекста" - это очевидный тупик, если не путь в никуда.

Comment: Это кто же Вам сказал такое про грамматику? С точки зрения грамматики, как раз неполное предложение так и определяется: отсутствующий член субъективно восстанавливается из контекста и предложение называется контекстуально-неполным, а ещё есть ситуативно-неполные, диалогически неполные и эллиптические, но сказуемые в них могут быть только 3 лица, никак не 1 или 2, а тем более не безличные, безличные глаголы только в безличных предложениях. Это азбука грамматики (синтаксиса).

Comment: >Это кто же Вам сказал такое про грамматику?   
  
Что именно? У меня была одна единственная **существенная** мысль про однородные члены. В вашем тексте (чуть не сказал "отповеди") нет ни слова про это.

Comment: Высший грамматический пилотаж. Благоговейно прислушиваюсь к корифеям. Свое мнение жгу в топке)))

Comment: Людмила! Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понимаю, формальная грамматика не противоречит трактовке предложений (причем - всех трех) ни как простых, ни как сложных. Поэтому спор не о правильности разбора, а о вкусах, какими бы авторитетами то или иное решение не освящалось.

На мой вкус первые два предложения равноправно можно трактовать и как простые, и как составные. 
Что касается последнего, то тут вступает в силу соображение естественной простоты объяснения (известное как "бритва Оккама"). Из двух равновозможных вариантов надо выбирать более простой. Более простой тут - "простое предложение с однородными членами", нет?

//========================

Людмила, мне нужно время, чтобы Ваши ссылки посмотреть и осмыслить, а я и так разрываюсь. Но одно могу сказать сейчас. Вы все скатываетесь на методику и школьные дела. Автору вопроса, может, это и интересно, но не мне. Грамматика существует безотносительно к тому, что о ней думает методист средней руки.

Comment: Не совсем так Иду и пою  не может быть простым:здесь "Я" не пропущено, оно избыточно. Второе - да, верно."На улице светло и солнечно" не может квалифицироваться как простое односоставное с однород. сказуемыми, т.к.однородными сказуемыми называются 2 сказуемых, относящихся к одному подлежащ., а здесь нет и не может быть подлежащего. Это противоречит определению однородных членов. У них просто общее обстоятельство "на улице", но это два односоставных безличных. В любом учебном заведении ответ "простое с одн. чл."будет принят как ошибочный.Кстати, СОСТАВНЫХ предложений не бывает, только сложные.

Comment: >Иду и пою не может быть простым:здесь "Я" не пропущено, оно избыточно.  
  
Только не с точки зрения грамматики. Стилистически - может быть, но это не то, о чем стоит говорить. Короче - тот же субъективизм.

>т.к.однородными сказуемыми называются 2 сказуемых, относящихся к одному подлежащ., а здесь нет и не может быть подлежащего    
  
Это надо обдумать. С одной стороны верно, с другой никак не может быть взято за определение. Ибо понятие однородных членов не завязано конкретно на сказуемое. Что ж, нам для каждого случая свое определение изобретать?

Comment: >а здесь нет и не может быть подлежащего   
  
А почему отсутствующее подлежащие нельзя считать одним и тем же?  Я как математик как раз склонен считать, что все пустые множества равны. Если у Васи нет денег, и у Пети нет денег, то у Пети и Васи денег поровну, нет? 
Если у первого сказуемого нет подлежащего и у второго нет подлежащего, что мне мешает считать, что это одно и тоже отсутствующее подлежащее? Это я "на пальцах", так сказать, суть надеюсь, понятна.

Comment: Мне-то понятно, а Вам понятно, что нельзя сказать "одно и то же подлежащее", если его нет и быть не может. Ваше выражение алогично и с точки зрения математики тоже. Если чего-то нет, мы не ищем, сколько этих "чего-то" и какие они. ИХ НЕТ, к ним ничего не относится, значит, и однородных членов нет.Если к 5 не прибавлено 7 или 4, какая разница, что не прибавлено? Можем сказать, что не прибавлены одинаковые числа, можем сказать, что не прибавлены разные числа. Зачем о них говорить и усложнять высказывание, если этих членов НЕТ?

Comment: >а Вам понятно, что нельзя сказать "одно и то же подлежащее", если его нет и быть не может.  

Мне понятно обратное. Иначе бы не стал об этом говорить. Если подлежащего нет ни там ни там, то оно одинаковое. Пустое. Мне бывает затруднительно понять, почсему этотго не понимают мои собеседники - это да. Я понимаю, что в быту "равенство" вполне может наличие, но тут-то речь идет о строгих формулировках. 

>Зачем о них говорить и усложнять высказывание, если этих членов НЕТ? 
  
Так оно упрощается! В сравнении с вариантном "их НЕТ, но они разные".

Comment: Вообще, похоже спор стал терминологическим - т.е. ни о чем. 
Вы согласны с заменой формулировки на "однородные сказуемые - те которые относятся к одному **существующему** (или **возможному**) подлежащему?" 
Если да, то давайте говорить об этом. Потому как я лично не согласен в принципе с тем, что однородность каких-либо членов предложения определяется через существование какого-то ещё члена, пусть даже подлежащего. Где модно такую формулировку найти?

Comment: Согласна, но в безличном НЕВОЗМОЖНО подлежащее, а в определённо-личном оно уже содержится в форме глагола, а не "возможно".
http://edu.glavsprav.ru/info/odnorodnye-chleny-predlozheniya/
Однородными называются такие члены предложения, которые являются одним и тем же членом предложения, относятся к одному и тому же члену предложения и соединяются друг с другом сочинительной связью.
Однородные члены предложения:
1. Отвечают на один и тот же вопрос
2. Зависят от одного и того же слова
3. Произносятся с перечислительной интонацией
http://5-ege.ru/odnorodnye-chleny/

Comment: http://ruyaz.ru/sintaksicheskij-razbor-prostogo-predlozheniya/ 
Первый тип ошибок в ЕГЭ связан с необходимостью разграничения односоставных и двусоставных неполных предложений.
Как уже было сказано, определённо-личное предложение мы диагностируем по форме главного члена: сказуемое в нём выражено глаголом в форме 1 и 2 лица ед.и мн. числа изъяв. накл. , и в повелит.накл.; производитель действия определён и может быть назван личными местоимениями 1 и 2 лица я, ты, мы, вы. 
Я иду и пою - простое с однородн. чл. Иду и пою - два опр.-личных.
Не путайте Лорану.Ей нужны не фантазии, а научный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Как раз грамматика потому и создана, чтобы можно было понимать друг друга, и, как вы понимаете, это касается письменной речи. Грамматика показывает, как мы мыслим. Поэтому грамматика языка вместе с математикой является основой развития абстрактного мышления детей, что и делает их образованными, грамотными.Никаких личных вкусов и представлений быть не может. Грамматика - это уже итог многочисленных наблюдений, исследований,анализа.Что касается грамматики русского языка, то она исключительно хорошо разработана, продумана, обеспечена примерами. Требуется лишь проявлять культуру языка, осознавая норму, нежели придумывать своё, ссылаясь на вкусы. Нелепость уже продемонстрирована, когда неким указом предложено слово "кофе" считать  мужским и средним родом одновременно: он, мой кофе; оно, моё кофе. Помните? Или, например, работающие со словом журналисты забыли, что хорошо и просто, грамотно  сказать: "пятеро рабочих" , но не "пять рабочих"; "через две недели", но не "через пару недель".